# magento where to start foot print

Tags: magento

I am working with giftcard and I want to investigate some behavior of giftcards. Being new to magento I am not sure where to start looking for a url

```
http://mysite.com/index.php/myspecificfolder/giftcardaccount/new
```

I am not sure what giftcardaccount is ? is it a folder or an action?
Also would be interested in "new"

Magento ver. 1.10.0.1

any help will be appreciated
thanks

Comment: You are using gift cards as a third party module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`giftcardaccount` is a controller.

Look in:  `/app/code/core/Enterprise/GiftCardAccount/controllers/Adminhtml/GiftcardaccountController.php`

The URL maps to the newAction() method.